# HTML5 video with redirect URL as source

Tags: php, html, url, redirect, video

So I have a HTML5 video player that works fine with a direct url as the source. However when I set the source as a url that links to a direct url, it won't work. Is there anyway to make it work? I am using PHP if that helps.

```
<video src="<?php echo $link; ?>" width="640" height="360" poster="testy/vplayer/media/poster.jpg" tabindex="0" controls="controls"></video>
```

The link is
http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=ff1c9d4cf38db476&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=sensitive_content=yes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1387666335&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=517DDFA9BB4265FC0E36CD19B7AEF96030DEF3BF.BDC3F29A59A031DC805381CDA22357227A7B4624&key=lh1

Comment: Redirects don't matter.  The browser will follow them.  There is probably something wrong with your URL, such as a cookie not allowing access or something.  Also, be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` around any variable data you're using in the context of HTML.

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: what does the generated html look like? is the src attribute the same as the link you posted above?

Comment: I've got a similar issue in  android(4.4.2) chrome browser where I'm specifying a redirect URL for the video src attribute. But, when I debugged the app using chrome debugger, I'm getting a warning like "Caution provisional headers are shown" . When I googled it, I came to know that its shown when the request is not actually fired by the browser. This is happening in android browsers only. 

 Any hints/explanation is highly appreciated !!!